# ASP.NET MVC Using code first, one to many CRUD

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, one-to-many

I am developing ASP.NET MVC webapp. I am using code first approach. My model classes are:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public PostType PostType { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeSubmitted { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string CSS { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Asset
{
    public int AssetID { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public AssetType AssetType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string EmbeddedCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeSubmitted { get; set; }

    public string ImageMineType { get; set; }
    public Byte[] AssetData { get; set; }

    public string CSS { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

}
```

Problem I am having is when I am trying to create `Asset`, only `Asset`. When I am trying to accomplish that, the `Post` is created also. The same is happening when I am trying to add new `Asset` to existing `Post`.

This works fine (creating a `Post` with `Asset`):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddPost(InspiredByModel data, HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    Post post = new Post();
    Asset asset = new Asset();

    if (image != null)
    {
        asset.ImageMineType = image.ContentType;
        asset.AssetData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
        image.InputStream.Read(asset.AssetData, 0, image.ContentLength);
    }
    post.Name = data.Name;
    post.Description = data.Description;
    asset.DateTimeSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
    post.DateTimeSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
    post.Assets = new List<Asset>();
    post.Assets.Add(asset);

    db.Posts.Add(post);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View("Index");
}
```

This does not work (new `Post` is created also, and `Asset.postId` is assigned to newly crated `Post`):
(NOTE: The `PostId` is hard coded for testing purposes)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AssetUploader(Asset asset, HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    if (image != null)
    {
        asset.ImageMineType = image.ContentType;
        asset.AssetData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
        image.InputStream.Read(asset.AssetData, 0, image.ContentLength);
    }

    var post = db.Posts.Where(p => p.PostId == 1).FirstOrDefault();

    asset.DateTimeSubmitted = DateTime.Now;

    post.Assets.Add(asset);
    db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;


    db.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}
```

I am looking for help/explanation/solution for my questions:

1. What is best practice to manage the One To Many relation using Entity Framework and Linq?
2. Why I can't create new `Asset` without automatically created and assigned new `Post`?
3. Can I create `Asset` first and then assign the `Post` to it?
4. How to add/remove `Asset` for existing `Post`?

UPDATE:

```
public class AssetConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Asset>
{
    internal AssetConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasOptional(i => i.Post)
            .WithMany(e => e.Assets)
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.PostId);
    }
}

public class PostConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
    internal PostConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasOptional(i => i.Assets) ;
    }
}
```

With these configurations the app behaves still the same

Comment: What is the relationship in the database between `Asset` and `Post`?

Comment: the problem is that by default EF stablishes a required relationship, to answer 2 and 3 you need to make that relationship optional (0 to many)

Comment: Re: barrick, one to many. one Asset can have many Posts

Comment: Re: barrick and bto.rdz: check the updated question

Comment: Re: @bto.rdz trying now to create many to many like that: <code>public class AssetConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Asset>
    {
        internal AssetConfiguration()
        {
            this.HasMany(i => i.Posts)
                .WithMany(c => c.Assets)
                .Map(mc =>
                {
                    mc.MapLeftKey("AssetId");
                    mc.MapRightKey("PostId");
                    mc.ToTable("PostHaveAssets");
                });
        }
    }</code> the problem is still happening. i can't update the Post with new Asset too.

Comment: I don't understand why in the second case a `Post` is created as well. The way the code looks this is unexpected behavior. It is a pretty standard way to handle 1-many associations with EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for help, The problem was in my code. i was posting to wrong method. the code is working fine.